Style-dictionary - Design tokens to scss mixins as css
my challange is that I want to make export from json to the scss mixins that will have css variables in it.
I'm getting json from figma(token studio) in the structure of tokens/designSystem/semantic.json,core.json, and token/designSystem/components/[anyComponent]
I have exported that is creating scss styles from this json, but I need to make mixins with css variables
This is my buildStyleDictionary.mjs:
import StyleDictionary from "style-dictionary";
import { readFile, readdir, rm } from "fs/promises";
import path from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

const configPath = path.join(__dirname, "config.json");
const config = JSON.parse(await readFile(configPath, "utf-8"));

const buildDir = path.join(__dirname, "style-dictionary");

// Remove the existing build directory to prevent duplicates
await rm(buildDir, { recursive: true, force: true });

// Register filters for each foundation type based on $type or prefix in semantic.json and core.json
const foundationTypes = [
  "color",
  "elevation",
  "size",
  "border",
  "font",
  "line",
  "spacing",
];
foundationTypes.forEach((type) => {
  StyleDictionary.registerFilter({
    name: `is${type.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + type.slice(1)}Token`,
    filter: (token) =>
      token.$type === type ||
      ((token.filePath.includes("semantic.json") ||
        token.filePath.includes("core.json")) &&
        token.name.startsWith(`${type}-`)),
  });
});

// Function to dynamically generate component-specific SCSS files
async function getComponentFiles() {
  const componentDir = path.join(__dirname, "tokens/designSystem/Component");
  const componentFiles = await readdir(componentDir);
  return componentFiles.map((file) => ({
    destination: `Component/${file.replace(".json", ".scss")}`,
    format: "scss/variables",
    filter: {
      filePath: `tokens/designSystem/Component/${file}`,
    },
  }));
}

const componentFiles = await getComponentFiles();

const sd = new StyleDictionary({
  ...config,
  platforms: {
    ...config.platforms,
    scss: {
      ...config.platforms.scss,
      files: [
        // Generate semantic and core as whole files without filtering by type
        {
          destination: "semantic.scss",
          format: "scss/variables",
          filter: {
            filePath: "tokens/designSystem/semantic.json",
          },
        },
        {
          destination: "core.scss",
          format: "scss/variables",
          filter: {
            filePath: "tokens/designSystem/core.json",
          },
        },
        // Generate foundation files in the Foundations folder
        ...foundationTypes.map((type) => ({
          destination: `Foundations/${type}.scss`,
          format: "scss/variables",
          filter: `is${type.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + type.slice(1)}Token`,
        })),
        // Component-specific files
        ...componentFiles,
      ],
    },
  },
});

sd.buildAllPlatforms();

console.log(
  "Style Dictionary build completed with semantic, core, Foundations, and Component SCSS files.",
);

Config.json:
  "source": [
    "./tokens/SignFace/semantic.json",
    "./tokens/SignFace/core.json",
    "./tokens/SignFace/Component/*.json"
  ],
  "platforms": {
    "scss": {
      "transformGroup": "scss",
      "buildPath": "style-dictionary/"
    },
    "css": {
      "transformGroup": "css",
      "buildPath": "style-dictionary/css/",
      "files": [
        {
          "destination": "variables.css",
          "format": "css/variables"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

Structure after export

Result
$label-font-family: Hind;
$label-font-weigth: 500;
$label-line-height: 100%;
$label-font-size: 14;
$label-text-base: #333e4a;
$label-gap: 4px;
$label-icon-size: 16px;
$label-icon-border-width: 1px; 

Expected Result
@mixin reset-list {
  --label-font-family: Hind;
  --label-font-weigth: 500;
  --label-line-height: 100%;
  --label-font-size: 14;
  --label-text-base: #333e4a;
  --label-gap: 4px;
  --label-icon-size: 16px;
  --label-icon-border-width: 1px; 
} 

